# How do I use third party type declarations for react-table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

react-table v7 has no typescript support yet. I found this, [react-table-7.0.0-beta.12.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/tsujp/3a67bb663296a1084516808bf9b807c4)

How do I use it?